# Ошибка в socket.sendto: OSError: [Errno 22] Недопустимый аргумент

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

В коде я считываю всё из JSON файла и загружаю в переменные.

Но когда я использую в:

```
socket.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), server)
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Недопустимый аргумент.

Как только я пробoвал ввести в эти переменные те же данные что и в JSON, то тогда всё работало отлично.

Загружаю данные в переменные таким образом:

```
    Config = open("Host.json", "r")

    Base = load(Config)
    Host = Base["ip"]
    Port = Base["port"]
    key = Base["key"]

    server = (Host, Port)
```

Я проверял что `server` выдаёт правильные данные с помощью `print()`, данные оказались идентичные.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

PS Обязательно должно быть использован JSON файл.

Comment: Совет: называйте переменные с маленькой буквы — это стандарт на питоне.

Comment: Это исправило мою ошибку :D спасибо большое за совет

Comment: в смысле?... ;)

Comment: @S4MMEX [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте данные из файла:

```
import json

with open('Host.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Сохраните в переменные:

```
host = data["ip"]
port = data["port"]
key = data["key"]
```